# GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES vs tf.trainable_variables()

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` is the same as `tf.trainable_variables()` ?

Is `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` actually `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`?

Looks like networks successfully trains with:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(config.LEARNING_RATE)
with tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)):
    self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(self.loss, var_list=tf.trainable_variables())
```

but not with

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(config.LEARNING_RATE)
with tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)):
    self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(self.loss)
```

According to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize):

```
var_list: Optional list or tuple of Variable objects to update to minimize loss. Defaults to the list of variables collected in the graph under the key GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES.
```

Also as I can see in batch normalization example code `var_list` is omited:

```py
  x_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=training)

  # ...

  update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
  with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Comment: Yes, it is the [same](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables). Probably the problem somewhere else in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass `var_list` to the `minimize()` function the variables would be retrieved in a following way (taken from `compute_gradients()` [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py)):

```py
if var_list is None:
      var_list = (
          variables.trainable_variables() +
          ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_RESOURCE_VARIABLES))
```

If you haven't defined any `ResourceVariable` instances that somehow not in `tf.trainable_variables()` the result should be the same. My guess is that the problem is somewhere else.

You could try to perform some test prior to call to `minimize()` to be sure that you don't have `ResourceVariable`s that are not in `tf.trainable_variables()`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
    with tf.name_scope('network'):
        logits = tf.layers.dense(x, units=2)

    var_list = (tf.trainable_variables()
                + tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_RESOURCE_VARIABLES))
    assert set(var_list) == set(tf.trainable_variables())
```